# Why value is coming same on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `Table TR` there is define control types with `fa-chevron-down` font awesome icon.

I want:
When i click on `fa-chevron-down` font awesome icon then open a `control types` now its two types (`input control` and `email control`) but it may be multiple.

When i click on `control types` then it is change the main value which are given in `Table TR`.

It is working fine for first `fa-chevron-down` font awesome icon click when i click on second `fa-chevron-down` then both `Table TR` value changed, why i'm not able to understand.

My Code:

```js
 $('body').on('click', '.select-response-type-btn', function (e) {
            var thisClick = $(this);
            $('.select-response-type-box').show();
            $('.response-menu-item').click(function () {
                var thisMunuItemHtml = $(this).html();
                $('.select-response-type-box').hide();
                $(thisClick).prev('.response-menu-item').html(thisMunuItemHtml);
            });
        });
```

```css
        .d-custom-none{ display: none;}
        .select-response-type-box{ border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js"
        integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="type-selector">
                        <div class="response-menu-item">
                            <div class="selected-icon-circle icon-text-light-green">
                                <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <span>Date & Time</span>
                        </div>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down chevron-custom select-response-type-btn" id="type_btn1"></i>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="type-selector">
                        <div class="response-menu-item">
                            <div class="selected-icon-circle icon-text-light-green">
                                <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <span>Date & Time control</span>
                        </div>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down chevron-custom select-response-type-btn" id="type_btn2"></i>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>


    <div class="select-response-type-box d-custom-none">
        <div class="response-menu-item">input control</div>
        <div class="response-menu-item">email control</div>
    </div>
```

Answer will appreciated!

Comment: the problem here seems to be the fact that you are trying to grab the click event on the entire div element containing both elements. So the first time it grabs your first element, the second time, it grabs, your second element, but since this is a click event it will first update the first element, and then immediately after update the second element. maybe change the event from 'click' to 'mouseup'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a lot of time made an working example.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taiwanhotdog/om4bpfe1/8/)

```
var clickIndex = 0;
$('body').on('click', '.select-response-type-btn', function () {
    clickIndex = $(this).parent().parent().parent().index();
    console.log(clickIndex);
    var thisClick = $(this);
    $('.select-response-type-box').show();
    $('.response-menu-item').click(function () {
        var thisMunuItemHtml = $(this).html();
        $('.select-response-type-box').hide();

        $('.type-selector').find('.response-menu-item').eq(clickIndex).html(thisMunuItemHtml);
        //$(thisClick).prev('.response-menu-item').html(thisMunuItemHtml);
    });
});
```

1. Why you use HTML Table ?? It's hard to get `index` between div and tr.
2. The most important is jquery selector `.select-response-type-btn` return wrong position. you must print click index like `clickIndex = $(this).parent().parent().parent().index();` if clickIndex return correct index then your example will working.